# Get every pair-wise combination of values between two lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists;

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b  = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I know I can get every permutation of these two lists like so:

```
for r in itertools.product(a, b): print (r[0] + r[1])
```

But what I'm looking for is every pairwise combination stored in a tuple.  So, for example, some combinations would be:

```
[(A, 1), (B, 2), (C, 3), (D, 4)]
[(A, 1), (B, 3), (C, 2), (D, 4)]
[(A, 1), (B, 4), (C, 3), (D, 2)]
[(A, 1), (B, 3), (C, 4), (D, 2)]
[(A, 1), (B, 2), (C, 4), (D, 3)]
```

So it would iterate through every possible combination so that no letter has the same number value.  I'm at a loss for an efficient way to do this (particularly since I need to scale this to three lists in my actual example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a lot easier than you think.  What about:

```
import itertools

a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

for aperm in itertools.permutations(a):
    for bperm in itertools.permutations(b):
        print(list(zip(aperm, bperm)))
```

First outputs:

```
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '4')]
...
```

(There are 576 lines printed for these two 4-element lists)

**Edit:** If you want to generalize this to more iterables, you could do something like:

```
import itertools

a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

gens = [itertools.permutations(lst) for lst in (a,b)]

for perms in itertools.product(*gens):
    print(list(zip(*perms)))
```

Which outputs the same thing, but could be easily extended, e.g.

```
import itertools

a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
c = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

gens = [itertools.permutations(lst) for lst in (a,b,c)]   # add c

for perms in itertools.product(*gens):                    # no change
    print(list(zip(*perms)))                              # ''
```

Comment: Ah! This is so much easier than what I was doing.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

We can make permutations of one of the lists (for example here the latter one), and then zip each permutation together with the first list, like:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import permutations

def pairwise_comb(xs, ys):
    return map(partial(zip, xs), permutations(ys))
```

or in case all subelements should be lists (here these are still iterables that can take a specific shape when you "materialize" these):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import permutations

def pairwise_comb(xs, ys):
    return map(list, map(partial(zip, xs), permutations(ys)))
```

For the given sample input, we obtain:

```
>>> for el in pairwise_comb(a, b):
...     print(list(el))
... 
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '1'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '1')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '1')]
[('A', '3'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '3'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '3'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '4')]
[('A', '3'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '1')]
[('A', '3'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '3'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '1')]
[('A', '4'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '4'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '4'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '3')]
[('A', '4'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '1')]
[('A', '4'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '1'), ('D', '2')]
[('A', '4'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '1')]
```

This thus results in 24 possible ways to combine this, since the order of `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` and `'D'` remains fixed, and the 4 characters can be assigned in 4! ways, or *4! = 4×3×2×1 = 24*.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much.  Because you and jedwards answered at the same time, but he has fewer reputation points, I'll have to award him the checkmark.  I never knew about partial, though, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with `yield` for a no-import solution:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b  = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
def combinations(d, current = []):
  if len(current) == 4:
    yield current
  elif filter(None, d):
    for i in d[0]:
      _d0, _d1 = [c for c in d[0] if c != i], [c for c in d[1] if c != d[1][0]]
      yield from combinations([_d0, _d1] , current+[[i, d[1][0]]])

for i in combinations([a, b]):
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
[['A', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['D', '4']]
[['A', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['C', '4']]
[['A', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['B', '3'], ['D', '4']]
[['A', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['B', '4']]
[['A', '1'], ['D', '2'], ['B', '3'], ['C', '4']]
[['A', '1'], ['D', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['B', '4']]
[['B', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['D', '4']]
[['B', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['C', '4']]
[['B', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['D', '4']]
[['B', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['A', '4']]
[['B', '1'], ['D', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['C', '4']]
[['B', '1'], ['D', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['A', '4']]
[['C', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['B', '3'], ['D', '4']]
[['C', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['B', '4']]
[['C', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['D', '4']]
[['C', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['A', '4']]
[['C', '1'], ['D', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['B', '4']]
[['C', '1'], ['D', '2'], ['B', '3'], ['A', '4']]
[['D', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['B', '3'], ['C', '4']]
[['D', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['B', '4']]
[['D', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['C', '4']]
[['D', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['A', '4']]
[['D', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['B', '4']]
[['D', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['B', '3'], ['A', '4']]
```